# How do the trading mechanism in NYSE and Nasdaq differ?

Tags: stock-markets, stock-exchanges, nasdaq, nyse

I've read and watched a decent amount of material and YouTube videos on the web, but still can't seem to get a grip on exactly how trading mechanisms in the NYSE and the Nasdaq differ.

I think I have a pretty good understanding on how it works in the Nasdaq: We have market participants, which are basically market makers, dealers and brokers, which enter their bids and asks to the *order book*.  The order book is basically two queues: one for bids, and one for asks. These queues are sorted first by price, and then by time, forming the price-time model.

So basically it looks like this: we have the bid queue, which at its top we have the best bid - i.e. the highest price participants are willing to pay for a given security - along with a *bid size* which is the quantity of securities that participants are willing to buy at this price.

Then, we have the same queue but for the asks. The top of this queue holds the *lowest* price that participants are willing to take in order to sell that security. Whenever a seller is willing to sell at the price that is equal or lower than the best bid price, or a buyer is willing to buy at an equal or higher price of that the best ask, a transaction is made.

If I got that correctly, it's pretty simple. So basically in the Nasdaq we have a completely algorithm-managed mechanism that is responsible for matching bids and asks.

But I just couldn't find a decent explanation of how things work over at the NYSE. I understand there's something called Designated Market Makers who are responsible for "maintaining an orderly and fair market", but I just can't understand what it means. I also keep reading about "participants submit competitive bids and asks", which, as far as I understand, holds true for the Nasdaq as well.

Can someone explain to me, or at least refer me to a good resource to help me understand how it works?

Comment: There's no conceptual difference anymore, all exchanges operate similarly and differ in fees they charge and the listing requirements